# Why am I receiving a non-nullable field error and is to correct to user ForeignKey to relate the tables with each other?

Tags: python, django, django-models, frameworks

This is my code and I keep receiving an error!

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class topics(models.Model):
    topic_level             = models.BooleanField()
    topic_name              = models.TextField()
    topic_question          = models.ForeignKey('questions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic_answer            = models.ForeignKey('answers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic_image             = models.ForeignKey('images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class questions(models.Model):
    question_description    = models.TextField()
    questions_type          = models.BooleanField()
    question_answer         = models.ForeignKey('answers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_image          = models.ForeignKey('images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class answers(models.Model):
    description             = models.TextField()
    answer_image            = models.ForeignKey('images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class images (models.Model):
    image_blob              = models.BinaryField()
```

This is the error:

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'answer_image' to answers
>   without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to
>   populate existing rows). sting rows). Please select a fix:  1) Provide
>   a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null
>   value for this column)  2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

I would like to know if I add a default value, will it affect the relationship between the tables? And what value to add? Does a random value do the job?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add non-nullable field. So, when you run migrations django need to populate this fields with something.

Make this filed nullable:

```
answer_image = models.ForeignKey('images', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
```

Then you will need to delete your last migration and create new and them migrate.

Comment: I have tried many solutions and none of them is working!
Thanks

Comment: Did you deleted your last migration and create it again?

Comment: This did work, sorry it was my mistake, I had not deleted the files themselves. I am truly thankful.

Answer (score 0):

It's probaby because you have made a `migration` earlier on the `model` without the `answer_image` field. So if you don't specify a `default` attribute or make it `null` and `blank`, django warns you to provide a default because `the database needs something to populate existing row`, if there were rows you had inserted then, django would want something to fill those rows in that field since its not `null` and cannot be `null` or `blank`, even if the table is empty, django will still warn you.

So do the following:

#### First Option

Follow the prompt that django prints in the console, select option 1 and provide a default to fill up existing rows

> Edit: The value cannot be anything random. But of data type `images` as specified by the `answer_image` field, so you enter a `foreign_key` corresponding to an `images` object/row since  django adds an `id` field to all models.

or

#### Second Option

Add the following attributes to your `answer_image` field as folows:

```
answer = models.ForeignKey(images, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Then apply your migration (I've suggested the second option because I am assuming you would not want a scenario where a row deleted in the `images` table `cascading` all the corresponding rows in the `answer` table, so in this case, a deletion will set the `answer_image` field `null`)

Comment: The second option is not working! I am still having the same error. And could you please show me how to do the first option!

Comment: use `answer_image` = not `image` i made a mistake there, it should work. or just enter `1` when prompted to provide a one off default